# SQLiteException: no such table: login

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, authentication

Im trying to make a login using Sqlite Database Browser which is basically in the asset folder. Whenever I sign in, the app is always closing, getting an error about no such table as login.

In my database broswer there's such a table but in ddms, only the android_metadata is shown and no such table as login is existed. Please help me.

Here is my DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  

private static String DB_NAME = "cafs";  
private static int DB_Version = 2;
private SQLiteDatabase db;  
private final Context context;  
private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.trialngiba/databases/";  

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {  
super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_Version);  
this.context = context;  

}  

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {  


      boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();  
      if (dbExist) {  
     try {  
       copyDataBase();  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       throw new Error("Error copying database");  
      }  
      } else {  
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     if (db.isOpen()){
         db.close();
         try {  
           copyDataBase();  
          } catch (IOException e) {  
           throw new Error("Error copying database");  
          }  
     } else {
     try {  
       copyDataBase();  
      } catch (IOException e) {  
       throw new Error("Error copying database");  
      }  
     }
      }
      }  

private boolean checkDataBase() {  
File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);  
return dbFile.exists();  
}  

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {  

InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);  
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;  
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);  
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
int length;  
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);  
}  

// Close the streams  
myOutput.flush();  
myOutput.close();  
myInput.close();  

}  
public  DatabaseHelper open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close() 
{
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
{
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);


    db.insert("login", null, newValues);

}
public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
{

    String where="USERNAME=?";
    int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("login", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;

 return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
}   
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("login", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
 if(cursor.getCount()<1)
 {
    cursor.close();
    return "NOT EXIST";
 }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;                
}
public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
{

    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

 String where="USERNAME = ?";
    db.update("login",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
}       


@Override  
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  

}  

@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
Log.d ("onUpgrade first log", Integer.toString(db.getVersion()));

if (oldVersion == 1) {

    DB_Version = 2;
    db.setVersion(2);
    Log.d ("onUpgrade second log", Integer.toString(db.getVersion()));

}

else {
    Log.d("onUpgrade", "else-clause: Already upgraded!");
}  
}  
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
12-01 00:58:02.408: E/Trace(3081): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-01 00:58:09.822: E/SQLiteLog(3081): (1) no such table: login
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: login (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM login WHERE  USERNAME=?
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.example.trialngiba.DatabaseHelper.getSinlgeEntry(DatabaseHelper.java:131)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.example.trialngiba.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-01 00:58:09.851: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your **DB_PATH**, i don't think it's the assets path

Comment: The db_path is correct, because I've already copied it to that path. Check my copyDatabase() codes/

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose you forgot closing myOutput, and semi-written file is deleted by system.

Look the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html

and try to add flush() and close() to your code.

Comment: Yup , there are flush() and close() in my code. How can I do that?